# Using delegate() or live() with jQuery ui tabs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, delegates, live, jquery-ui-tabs

I'm rerendering part of a page which includes jQuery-ui tabs. After the rerender the tab headers are no longer bound to the event.

Can you initialise the tabs using delegate() or live() in the first place and avoid this issue or is it necessary to re-bind $('foo').tabs() afterwards?

Comment: Is it just the tab *events* that you want to use `delegate` with, or do you mean re-initializing the entire widget?

Comment: The section of the page that is rerendered contains (amongst other things) a tab structure. On rerender the tabs are no longer initialised (jquery-ui tab classes aren't applied). I'm using delegate to maintain click events after the rerender, how do I do the same with functions like $('foo').tabs() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is yes, you must call `$("foo").tabs()` again after appending content you want to tabify.

*However*, there is a very good [plugin called livequery](http://brandonaaron.net/code/livequery/docs) that will actually accomplish what you're after. With that plugin you can write code like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // When a new element with class "tabs" underneath the body element appears, apply the 
    // .tabs() function:

    $("body .tabs").livequery(function() {
        $(this).tabs();
    });
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/vpnJt/

If you don't want to use a plugin for this, I would move your initialization code for this type of thing into a function that you call in your AJAX success.

Comment: Whilst this didn't solve my specific problem, calling $('foo').tabs() after the rerender did work for other areas of the site where the whole tab structure was rerendered. 

I didn't fully understand my problem when I tried to articulate it, I was rerendering a background tab and the tab header rather than the whole tab structure. I have resolved my issue and posted it below as an answer but this is the most correct answer to my original question.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to attach the tab events to a parent element of the tabs that is not to be reloaded. To be on the safe side, you can always use `live()`, so it is at the root of the DOM tree. Or if you want to be more precise, you could do something like the following.

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="tabs"><!-- tabs to be reloaded --></div>
</div>
```

Assuming `#container` is not to be reloaded, you could do:

```
$('#container').delegate('#tabs', 'tabsshow', function(event, ui) {
  // some action when tabs has been shown
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is an issue with rerendering tabheaders. I was rerendering a background tab and, as the tabheader held a counter, I was rerendering the tabheader to increment the tab.

This broke the tab structure and there was no way of reapplying the event listener. The only jquery ui solution was to destroy and rebuild the tabs which was unacceptable in our situation.

I resolved the problem by simply rerendering *within* the background tab, and calling an oncomplete function which incremented the counter on the tabheader.